# android check if file exists with case sensitivity?

Tags: android, file

I have to change the title casing of a folder. Basically, on app startup I want to look for the old casing, and rename it if it is still there. So far in my tests, android ignores the casing, and reports the folder casing as whatever you send in. So basically

```
new File(PATH_WITH_OLD_CASING) == new File(PATH_WITH_NEW_CASING)
```

and it also seems to report the absolute path that you send in, without regards to what it is actually named in the file system. so

```
new File(PATH_WITH_OLD_CASING).getAbsolutePath() == PATH_WITH_OLD_CASING;
```

and

```
new File(PATH_WITH_NEW_CASING).getAbsolutePath() == PATH_WITH_NEW_CASING;
```

even though they refer to the same file.

So I am struggling to come up with a way to determine if the old casing is still there. I can probably do a listFiles on the parent directory to get the casing, but its the root of the SD Card, don't really want to do that everytime the app starts (doesn't seem like a very clean solution).

Any ideas?

Comment: note that case sensitivity is a property of the filesystem, not a property of Android. Android only follows what the filesystem driver says; in particular, on FAT/RFS, filename is case insensitive, while on ext4 filename is case sensitive. If you need to have a different comparison semantic than the filesystem's, then unfortunately you have to do the comparison yourself. Also, you should use .equals when comparing Objects in Java, unless the code you give is only an illustrative pseudocode that is misleadingly concrete.

Comment: illustrative pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: a not exactly ideal solution I came up with

```
if (parentDirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.contentEquals(DEPRECATED_FILE_NAME);
    }
   }).length > 0){
//old file exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say the directory is on the SD card, and that is most likely where your problem lies.

By default, the SD card is formatted as FAT, which preserves case but is case insensitive.

This meand that /sdcard/Hello is the same as /sdcard/HeLlO.

Now, the reason why `File` is not behaving as you expect, I believe, is because it is operating on the pathname you pass it, rather than reading what is present on the filesystem. Even if you open the file and it succeeds, I still wouldn't expect that it would update the path you give it, I'd expect it to just maintain an internal flag that the file was successfully opened.

You should use [getCanonicalPath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29) rather than getAbsolutePath():

> Most callers should use
>   getAbsolutePath() instead. A canonical
>   path is significantly more expensive
>   to compute, and not generally useful.
>   The primary use for canonical paths is
>   determining whether two paths point to
>   the same file by comparing the
>   canonicalized paths.

Comment: Just tested. Seems like getCanonicalPath behaves the same with respect to casing (always reports whatever you use in the constructor)

Comment: Interesting - I was hoping that since it resolves links, and the `.` and `..` directories that it would actually walk the directory tree and return the actual pathname. Unfortunately, digging into the Oracle Java docs suggests that even getCanonicalPath will operate on the cached pathname when at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could always convert the file name to a string value and then use the toUpper or toLower functions to check for the old file. It's a bit of an extra step in your solution, but might be the quickest way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: hmm, not sure what you mean here. the problem seems to be that I can't actually get the preserved, case sensitive value at all from the file system, so not sure how I can do any string comparisons on it.

Comment: What I had meant was that if you knew the old file name you were looking for, you could in theory convert the old value to all upper case and look for it that way.  For example: if KNOWNVALUEINUPPERCASE == (PATH_WITH_OLD_CASING).getAbsolutePath().toString.toUpper would give you a true/false statement to see if the old folder existed.  But it looks like you found a solution for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

hmm...
first try to list directory. sample code for listing directory is [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html)

after that compare them to your file name. hope it will work