# Renaming directory gives positive result code, but didn't rename

Tags: android

I know it's only cosmetic but the below code should rename my directory however it doesn't. The difference is just some capitalisation - but afaik Android is fully case sensitive when it comes to filenames. Like Linux normally is too.
The rename gives a true result, indicating the operation was successful. However the directory in question is NOT renamed, and it still has two capital D's.
I have previously used the same code to rename from /DeadDropDroid to /.DeadDropDroid and that works fine. Every time I run the below code the log says "success".

```
oldBasePath = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/.DeadDropDroid/");
if (oldBasePath.exists()) {
    if (oldBasePath.renameTo(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/.DeaddropDroid/")))
        Log.v(TAG, "Rename success.");
    else
        Log.v(TAG, "Rename fail.");
    }
```

Comment: Does it rename if you try to change it to name that is different other than capitalization such as renaming it to test?

Comment: Yes - it does. This is actually a second time I'm renaming; first from /DeadDropDroid to /.DeadDropDroid to make it a hidden directory. That works perfectly. I'm afraid the "case preserving but case insensitive" issue of FAT is the problem here. Will test later tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407396/android-check-if-file-exists-with-case-sensitivity/5407535#5407535) answer to a similar question. The key content is

*By default, the SD card is formatted as FAT, which preserves case but is case insensitive.*

I did some checks and can confirm that the mentioned `File` methods work 'case insensitive' on the SD card. You even can not check `oldBasePath.exists()` as ist also will return `true`if the LowerCase directory version exists instead of the UpperCase version. You have to read the directory content and compare the file/directory names you received with your pattern.

Renaming will also be a two step approach (via a temp File), e.g

```
.DeadDropDroid -> .DeadDropDroid_tmp -> .DeaddropDroid
```